# Contour Integration on a Rectangle showing that the vertical sides go to 0

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to integrate $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{x/4}}{1+e^x}$ using a rectangular contour.  I have solved to the point that integral is $\pi \sqrt{2}$ (using that $z = \pi i$).

My question is, I have solved the top and the bottom parts of the rectangle to acquire the answer, but I am having difficulty in proving that the vertical edges of the rectangle go to 0.  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Presumably the lower limit is $-\infty$.

Comment: Dear @user0430 I see that, although you have already asked 18 question in this site and received answers in most of them, you have not mark a best answer in any of them. You can do it so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that you think is the one that helped you the most. Please [read here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more detail.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the contour is a rectangle with vertices $(-A, A, -A+2\pi i,A+2\pi i)$ for $A>0$, we can solve for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{\frac{x}{4}}}{1+e^x}$ by integrating $f(z)=\frac{e^{\frac{z}{4}}}{1+e^z}$ over the contour and sending $A\to\infty$. Note that $f(z)$ is meromorphic in an open set containing this contour with exactly one simple pole at $z=\pi i$. The residue there is
$$
\text{res}_{\pi i}f=\lim_{z\to\pi i}\frac{e^{\frac{z}{4}}(z-\pi i)}{1+e^z}=e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}\lim_{z\to\pi i}\frac{z-\pi i}{1+e^z}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
by L'Hopital's rule.

The top side of the contour can be parametrized by $z=2\pi i+x$ as $x$ travels from $A$ to $-A$ (this is the leftward direction, in keeping with the counter-clockwise orientation of the contour). Thus setting $I$ to be the integral in question, we have
$$
\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{top} f(z)dz=\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{2\pi i+x}{4}}}{1+e^{{2\pi i+x}}}dx
=\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\frac{ie^\frac{x}{4}}{1+e^x}dx=-iI
$$

The side on the right (parametrized by $z=A+ix$) goes to zero because the
integral has finite length ($2\pi$) and the integrand $f(z)$ is bounded by
$$
\left|\frac{e^{\frac{A+ix}{4}}}{1+e^{A+ix}}\right| =
\frac{e^{\frac{A}{4}}|e^{ix}|}{|1+e^Ae^{ix}|}\leq\frac{e^{\frac{A}{4}}}{\left|e^A-1\right|}\to 0,
$$
and the left side similarly vanishes because we have the similar bound
$$
\frac{e^{-\frac{A}{4}}}{\left|e^{-A}-1\right|}\to\frac{0}{1}=0.
$$
Obviously the bottom side converges to the integral $I$, so for the whole contour we can apply the residue theorem to see
$$
\int_{\text{rectangle}}f(z)dz=I-iI+0+0=I(1-i)=2\pi i \cdot\text{res}_{\pi i}f=\sqrt{2}\pi(1-i)
$$
Therefore $I=\sqrt{2}\pi$.

Comment: Well done!  Nice solution.